# How granting Kosovo independence was a violation of international law?

Tags: international-relations

I heard that at that time when Kosovo was granted independence the Russia's side said that it was a violation of the international law. How was it a violation? Which points of the law were violated?

Comment: This question is good, but belongs more to [Politics SE Beta](http://politics.stackexchange.com/). Please consider moving your question there.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary I'm not sure, sounds more like history (albeit quite recent) to me.

Comment: @Lohoris to be honest, I am not absolutely sure. I stated the question [here](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/is-there-definition-of-history-which-separates-from-definition-of-politics)

Answer (score 7):

NATO used force, or the threat of force, to remove Kosovo from Serbia.

The UN charter, Article 2, paragraph 4:

> All Members shall refrain in their international relations from the
>   threat or use of force against the territorial integrity or political
>   independence of any state, or in any other manner inconsistent with
>   the Purposes of the United Nations.

Comment: Could you explain how this interesting fact answers the Qn?

Comment: @andy256 the NATO used force and threat of force to take Kosovo from Serbia, that is violate its territorial integrity.

Comment: To my thinking this is an overly simplistic analysis. As I recall there was a civil war at the time, multiple Security Council resolutions, and that people are still undergoing war crimes trials re their actions in Kosovo. So I don't think it's so black and white.

Comment: @andy256 - "As I recall there was a civil war at the time..." - When the independence was granted to Kosovo the war was still going on?! Are you sure?

Comment: @brilliant The [recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Kosovo) of [independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Kosovo_declaration_of_independence) post date the [KFOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovo_Force) involvement. To my mind, this answer confuses the KFOR involvement during the civil war with the declaration of independence, even though one led to the other. My earlier comment left out such detail, allowing it to be interpreted differently to my intended meaning :-)